# How can my friend and I share an exact development environment together while on different operating systems?

Tags: docker, vagrant

I use a Mac for development and deployment, and have a need for creating an isolated environment. I've been exploring vagrant and docker and it seems that in order to run Docker, I need to be on a linux environment. I'm running an instance of vagrant with Ubuntu, the same as my partner uses on their desktop.

My question is, can my partner run the docker container off their Ubuntu instance instead of having to setup Vagrant like myself? Does my server and app run inside my Docker instance? (I'm using MEAN).

Trying to build a workflow and piece it all together.

Answer (score 1):

He could probably get docker to run but packaging it all inside of a vagrant VM really is the way to go as that will keep it transportable across the board.

Comment: My understanding is that the docker container contains parts that make the server different from the client (his Ubuntu OS), making the environment the same no?

Comment: Yes but you still need to standup / configure the docker environment in a similar way across different hosts which is where vagrant and the ubuntu VM help you out.

Comment: I thought you setup everything in the container, then when it runs on a host OS it emulates the parts that are different from the base OS. I may be using incorrect terminology so bare with me lol.

Comment: for the most part, you have it correct.  If you ended up setting your docker install up with custom properties and such, the environment _might_ end up behaving differently, is what @WyattBarnett is trying to say.

Comment: alright thanks for clearing it up, seems like i just have to give team members the vagrant file

Comment: You can use vagrant new docker provider/provision. Like @WyattBarnett said you should set up a virtualbox VM and add a docker provider in it. Here 2 github examples : https://github.com/rllola/vagrant-docker  https://github.com/bubenkoff/vagrant-docker-example

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the vagrant file and just share the Docker images. There should be no detectable host differences from within the container.